# GET-SET property return null

Tags: c#, .net, oop, encapsulation

It's a very simple thing, I try the same thing as I found from the forms, a few times I get null

```
public class Variables_Log
    {   
        private int_Type_Parameter_Log;
        public int Type_Parameter_Log
        {
            get
            {
                return _Type_Parameter_Log;
            }
            set
            {
                _Type_Parameter_Log= value;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the part I use in the form.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
 Variables_Log variables_log = new Variables_Log();


 public void Write_Parameter_Log()
  {
    public string Log_Raw = "";
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\CAS_CW1 -                                     
    ORJINAL\\CAS_CW1\\Log_Parameter.txt", FileMode.Append, 
    FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
    variables_Log.Type_Parameter_Log = "INFO";

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

    if (fs != null)
    {
        Log_Raw = (variables_Log.Type_Parameter_Log);
        sw.WriteLine(Log_Raw);
        sw.Close();
    }
 }
```

}

Here, I am changing the value but not in the other class.
I could not resolve the issue

Comment: you haven't set that. you can't set it inside of a class directly.

Comment: how so? Where should I use it then?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Your description of the error doesn't make a lot of sense either. Can you provide the actual code and the actual error message? Like literally cut and paste.

Comment: I wrote abbreviated, when ı compile  no error, just I take null for the variable

Comment: Your posted code will not compile. Please provide the actual code you used.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: I shared it as short as possible.

Comment: We can't exactly help you if the post you post doesn't compile, and can't demonstrate your issue. Again, please post a [mre]. Please _read_ through that information.

Comment: I think the failed sample code is private int_Type_Parameter_Log; vs private int _Type_Parameter_Log;  You do not have space between data type and property name with leading underscore.  You could also default for sake of testing to do private int _Type_Parameter_Log = 47;  Just to see A value as declared upon creation of class.

Comment: It's absolutely impossible for the `Type_Parameter_Log` property to return `null`. It is typed as an `int` which cannot be `null`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple logger. you can use this concept for your problem.

```
public class Logger
{
    private string _path;

    public Logger(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public void Log(string row, string lable)
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Append))
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            var logString = $"#{lable} : {row}";
            sw.WriteLine(logString);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }

    public void LogInfo(string row)
    {
        Log(row, "Info");
    }

    public void LogError(string row)
    {
        Log(row, "Error");
    }
}
```

> Variable Location on Project in Program class

```
internal static class Program
{
    public static Logger Logger;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Logger = new Logger("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\CAS_CW1-ORJINAL\\CAS_CW1\\Log_Parameter.txt");

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

> **Now you can use logger on any form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.Logger.LogInfo("Hello World, Logger. I'm in Form 1");
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnForm2Log_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.Logger.LogError("Hello World, Logger. I'm in Form 2");
    }
}
```

[**Github code**](https://github.com/thisisnabi/Stackoverflow-Helps/tree/master/CSharp_PublicLogClass)